# Nested attributes: Only 1 out of 3 images shows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Post, Comment and comment_images. With every comment you can upload 3 images. I have a problem with displaying all 3 images - It displays just the last picture selected (1 image). I've used polymorphic association, because those images will belong to other things in the future.

form

```
<%= nested_form_for([@post, @comment], html: {multipart: true}, class: 'comments') do  |f| %>

  <%= f.text_area :content %>
...
    <%= f.fields_for :comment_images do |p| %>
        <%= p.file_field :image %>
        <%= p.file_field :image %>
        <%= p.file_field :image %>
    <% end %>
...
<% end %>
```

show

```
<% @comment.comment_images.each do |pic| %>
     <%= link_to image_tag(pic.image_url(:comment_thumb)), pic.image_url, target: :_blank if pic.image?  %>
<% end %>
```

comment_images

```
class CommentImage < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader 
end
```

comment

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  has_many :comment_images, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comment_images, :limit => 3
...
end
```

comments_controller

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :user_id, :post_id,
    comment_images_attributes: [:image, :attachable_id, :attachable_type])
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to repeat the `file` field. When using `accepted_nested_attributes_for` the `fields_for` will do the iteration for you. So change the form to this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :comment_images do |p| %>
    <%= p.file_field :image %>
<% end %>
```

This is not necessary:

```
    <%= p.file_field :image %>
    <%= p.file_field :image %>
    <%= p.file_field :image %>
```

Don't forget to initialize three child objects in your controller.

```
@comment = Comment.new(images: images) #=> where images is an array of three image objects
```

Comment: Now I have 1 field. I want 3 fields, so that you can select and upload 3 images separately (not 1 where you select 2-3 images at once)

Comment: @Absurdim Then initialise three child objects in your controller. You are seeing one field because you probably initialized only one.

Comment: Are you sure that is the right code? I get "undefined local variable or method `images' for..."

Comment: @Absurdim obviously, because `images` doesn't exist. I wrote that images should be an array of 3 image instances, the number you want. It was an example.

Comment: So, what would be in the code exactly? Write concrete code that works and that would display all 3 images on the show.

Comment: @Absurdim Whoaoa... I'm so sorry! Why don't I just write your whole program for you? Read the manual. I've already given you more than enough information and set you on your way. You need 3 times `@comment.comment_images.build` use your imagination!

Comment: That seems to be working. Sorry if I came across a bit rude. I accepted your answer.

Comment: @Absurdim hehe! No worries, I was messing about too! Nothing serious! Glad it works.